# javascript - OOP how javascript store functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have been using javascript Klass library for a while, and I am curious about how javascript store functions. For a common class and its instance in other OOP language, such as C++, the methods of the class instances, could be shared by all instances, so all methods in different instances could be stored only once in memory. So whatever we created many instances of the class, we just have one set of methods and shared in memory.

For javascript, is it similar? I have this question because I am a bit worried about javascript OOP performance, if in javascript, we created class and instance like this -

```
var A = {
    init: function () {
    },
    say: function (words) {
        console.log (words);
    }
};

var B = $.extends (A, {
    beep: function () {
        console.log (words);
    }
});
```

I think B actually copied A's property including function, not referenced to them, so it will re-allocate memory for them, not shared, am I wrong?

Now back to Klass library,

```
var Person = klass(function (name) {
  this.name = name
})
  .statics({
    head: ':)',
    feet: '_|_'
  })
  .methods({
    walk: function () {}
  });

var SuperHuman = Person.extend(function (name) {
  // super class is automagically called
})
  .methods({
    walk: function() {
      this.supr()
      this.fly()
    },

    fly: function() {}

  })

new SuperHuman('Zelda').walk();
```

In sub class and all instance, are they referenced to these functions or copied these functions?

Comment: You would need to know how $.extends works. that isn't a magic function, it's a function defined by something you have included on your page. My bet is it's just passing the function by reference, meaning the function is still only in memory once, but it's referenced in multiple places.

Comment: Functions are held by reference. To make a copy, it takes some ugly hackery, and then loses its original variable scope. But to test, do `A.beep === B.beep`. You'll find it's `true`.

Comment: I'm on my phone, so I have you do the actual searching: search for "prototype inheritance".

Comment: @blue: right but if you would define the methods inside the constructor , every instance would get their own copy.

Comment: @FelixKling: True. I was referring specifically to the `$.extend` example. Certainly two invocations of a function that creates a function will create two separate functions.

Comment: Like Felix said, search for prototypal inheritance. You should really have experience using it directly before using something like Klass. And then you may find that you don't need Klass at all. Or use TypeScript if you want better syntax that's forward compatible with ECMAScript 6.

Comment: Thanks for all, I think I got it and will try TypeScript definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question isn't fully possible to answer without digging into Klass (which I'm not familiar with, though I've seen similar), but I'm 99% sure that the functions are shared, not copied.

The most common OOP implementation that does *not* share function references is what Crockford calls [parasitic inheritance](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html). In this pattern, methods are added in the constructor, and are not shared:

```
function Person() {
    this.walk = function() { ... }
}

function Superman() {
    var self = new Person();
    self.fly = function() { ... }
}
```

But in most other cases, either using prototypical inheritance or composition-based inheritance, functions are referenced, not copied or recreated.

As a practical point, it would be very hard *not* to share functions by reference unless those functions were declared within a constructor or factory function of some kind. In order to copy the functions in the structure you've listed, you'd have to do something like `eval(fn.toString())`, which is possible but rarely used.

Comment: You are right. I can understand this like function is as same functional as object, and all objects are referenced.